# Working with AudioContext with a source from audio tag

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio

I'm building a music player and I'd like to add a pulsation effect depending on the track currently played.

Here some examples of what I'd want:

http://www.htmlfivewow.com/demos/hal/index.html

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/360-player/canvas-visualization.html

My problem is that in the first example, sound is loaded via xhr, and in the second it uses flash.

I'd want to be able to get the sound that I want to analyze from the audio tag.

I'm afraid it could not be possible, it would cause a big lack of security because we could load web pages instead of sound and then analyse it. Is there a solution anyway?

Comment: Asked a similar kind of question few seconds and then noticed your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like here is one implementation doing  over Web Audio API:

https://github.com/richtaur/audia/blob/master/audia.js

and background:

http://www.lostdecadegames.com/audia-is-a-library-for-simplifying-the-web-audio-api/

Comment: Works for me. It serves the same purpose by 1) emulating <audio> tag 2) giving you access to the AudioContext. Why you cannot use this?

Comment: I just want to build a personal music player and discover the audio api, and I'd want a "pretty" solution, using an overlay is not what I'm looking for. Even if audia seems to be good. And it uses also xhr to load the audio file. Thank you for your interest in my "problem" ;)

Answer (score 27):

You can use **createMediaElementSource** method in AudioContext.

```
<audio id="audio" src="test.mp3"></audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var context = new webkitAudioContext;
    var el = document.getElementById('audio');
    var source = context.createMediaElementSource(el);
    source.connect(context.destination);
    el.play();
</script>
```

Comment: I really like this method as it doesn't require prompting the user for permissions nor global input context, only the audio tag.