# <audio> style API or abstraction for AudioBuffer

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, audiobuffer

Does Javascript have abstractions which would provide  (MediaElement) API for AudioBuffer?

This would help to have AudioBuffer as a drop-in replacement for HTML5 audio element.

- You would not need to change the old playback code and event handlers
- You would still get access to effects, FFT data and such

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working with AudioContext with a source from audio tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078889/working-with-audiocontext-with-a-source-from-audio-tag)